# Unable to submit data from php jquery page posting data to another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm creating a php form using jquery. Trying to dynamically add rows and then submit to another page which inserts the data.

It is a store inventory form to supply multiple products in a single form rather than adding one product and going over the process back again. I have another form to submit same data which inserts single row of data and it works fine.I am trying to improve the same. If I comment out add row & delete row functions, submit works but for only one row. Vice versa, if I comment out submit button & function, I can dynamically add & delete rows. How to post data for multiple rows by connecting ajax to php for posting data is not clear. Also I need to post attached file which will be in pdf format for input id=Annexure.

```
<html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="insert_indents.php" method="post" name="indform" id="indform">
                <label for="Part_No">Part No.:</label>
                <input type="text" id="Part_No" name="Part_No" placeholder="Part No">
                <label for="Part_Make">Part Make:</label>
                <input type="text" id="Part_Make" name="Part_Make" placeholder="Part Make">
                <label for="Annexure">Attach File:
                <input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
                <input id="Annexure" name="Annexure" type="file" class="form-control" style='width:20em'/>
                </label>
                <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
                <input type="button" id="Submit" class="ind-row" id ="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="add_indent_details()" />
            </form>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Select</th>
                        <th>Part No</th>
                        <th>Part Make</th>
                        <th>Attached File</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button type="button" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>
            <script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/ajax.js"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".add-row").click(function(){
                        var Part_No = $("#Part_No").val();
                        var Part_Make = $("#Part_Make").val();
                        var Annexure= $("#Annexure").val();
                        var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + Part_No +"</td><td>" + Part_Make +"</td><td>" + Annexure+  "</td></tr>";
                        $("table tbody").append(markup);
                    });
                    // Find and remove selected table rows
                    $(".delete-row").click(function(){
                        $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
                            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                                $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <script>
                 $(document).ready(function(){
                 $("#Submit").click(function(){
                    var Part_No = $("#Part_No").val();
                    var Part_Make = $("#Part_Make").val();
                    var Annexure= $("#Annexure").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'insert_indents.php',
                        type :'post',
                        data :{Part_No:Part_No,Part_Make:Part_Make,Annexure:Annexure},
                        datatype :'text',
                        success:function(data)
                        {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I want to insert the data along with attached file into my database posting this data to a different page which contains insert query.
Thanks for your help.
I'm a newbie to PHP & ajax.

Comment: So the problem is that your file is not being sent via ajax?

Comment: Please post the JQuery code that you are using.

Comment: @AlexOdenthal Yes. Unable to send data as well as the attached file.

Comment: @Adamabdulshakoor Added the code in last script tag.